# How to copy text to local .env file with bash

Tags: bash

Is there a way in a shell script to copy text into a local .env file so that I can automate setting those environment variables?

example, I want to copy this to an .env file that sits in the same directory I'm already cd'd to

```
PIN=1
DEVICE_PREFIX=xxx
DEV=true
```

Comment: `echo foo > .env` ?

Comment: `printf '%s\n' 'PIN=1' 'DEVICE_PREFIX=xxx' 'DEV=true' >> .env`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

text=$(cat << EOF
PIN=1
DEVICE_PREFIX=xxx
DEV=true
EOF
)

# Specify the path to the .env file
env_file=".env"

# Copy the text to the .env file
echo "$text" > "$env_file"
```

Comment: @PositiveGuy you can simply do it on the command line as `cat > your.env << EOF ... EOF` To APPEND and not REPLACE use `cat >> your.env << EOF ... EOF`

Answer (score 2):

Well there are multiple approaches, one that I don't see here is the most simplest

```bash
echo "
PIN=1
DEVICE_PREFIX=xxx
DEV=true
" > .env
```

with `echo` can do multi line printing and then redirect the output to the file i.e `.env`

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

An alternative without creating/saving the data/input to a variable, something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

env_file=".env"

cat >> "$env_file" <<'EOF'
PIN=1
DEVICE_PREFIX=xxx
DEV=true
EOF
```

---

- The above construct is called [Here Documents](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Documents)

A note on the redirections ( > and >> ) from the shell.

- The `>>` appends to the existing non-empty file.

  - See  [Appending Redirected Output](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Appending-Redirected-Output)
- The `>` Replaces the data/contents of an existing non-empty file.

  - See [Redirecting Output](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirecting-Output)
- A word of caution, the `>` truncates an existing file, but both `>>` and `>` creates it if it does not exists.
- See [Redirections](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html)